# User avatar in zurb foundation 6 navbar (Top-bar)

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have a user's avatar in the top-bar but the arrow is on the right. How to get it on the left? I can't find that css anywhere. See pic:

[image]

The code used is in ruby on rails:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to image_tag(current_user.profile.avatar.url(:small), class: "img-circle tiny-img"), "#" %>
  <ul class="menu vertical">
    <li><%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_profile_path(current_user) %></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Also, how to change the color of the arrow?

Comment: share your current css

Comment: @GauravAggarwal well...Im using foundation 6 so I have no custom css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a css rule for `.is-dropdown-submenu-parent.is-down-arrow>a:before` and modify the css rule for `.is-dropdown-submenu-parent.is-down-arrow>a:after` like so:

```
.is-dropdown-submenu-parent.is-down-arrow>a:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px inset;
  border-color: #2199e8 transparent transparent;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.25rem;
  float: left;
  right: 5px;
}

.is-dropdown-submenu-parent.is-down-arrow>a:after {
  display: none;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/uvhcgdz0/)**

Change the `top` value for `.is-dropdown-submenu-parent.is-down-arrow>a:before` to change the arrow's vertical position.